# JQuery Mobile "Filter Items" showing under Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a JQuery Mobile web app, and have a quick question regarding a `listview`'s `data-filter`.

Photo of Visual Problem:

[image: headerImage]

Code Running the Page:

```
<section id="landmarks" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="appHeader"  data-theme="a">
        <h1>National Landmarks</h1>
    </header>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="landmarksList">
            <!--Fills Items-->
        </ul>
    </div>

<!--Toolbar Injection Code-->

</section>
```

I have tried applying padding and margins to the `listview` and the `header`, however, the search box still stays below the header.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding toolbars dynamically?

Comment: Yes. I am also generating the pages that are linked to the list dynamically.

Comment: You create a page and then you inject toolbars?

Comment: Yes, is this not correct?

Comment: I have updated the example to where the injection code is.

Comment: You should call `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();` after creating toolbars.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have called the reset height function after the toolbars. But it seems like the height problem actually comes from the function that dynamically creates the pages. I have tried to call this function after I inject the pages into the HTML body, but it still does not work. Do you have any ideas why adding pages dynamically would change the height of the active page?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without examining code used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with a Javascript function that was adding erroneous lines into the code.